# Increment two columns in database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have three columns in my database.

```
KEY_ID integer primary key autoincrement, KEY_MESSAGE string not null, KEY_POSITION integer not null
```

and i want to autoincrement both KEY_ID and KEY_POSITION. How can i do this?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352508/sqlite-multiple-autoincrement-columns

Comment: KEY_ID is already incrementing **spontaneously** (because it's defined as `autoincrement`). you can only increment KEY_POSITION.

Comment: Auto_increment field must be a key constraint. Either primary key or unique key.

Comment: From @DROIDDcoder suggestion i get that the value of autoincrement field cannot be altered, so is there any way i can copy the value of **KEY_ID** to **KEY_POSITION** on insertion of a record in database because i want to change the value of this field dynamically later on.